# Broadleaf Framework Integration Module Error

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have been able to download and run the demosite source code in eclipse luna

I was unable to change the broadleaf logo in the DemoSite project , so I downloaded the broadleaf framework source code and imported into eclipse . BLC framework is a multi-module project . On running clean install on the broadleaf sub-module all modules build successfully except the integration module which results in this following stack trace ( Edited )

```
       ------------------------------------------------------------------               -------------
```

### Test set: TestSuite

```
  Tests run: 153, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed:                 196.714 sec <<< FAILURE!
  testCheckout(org.broadleafcommerce.core.checkout.service.CheckoutTest)    Time elapsed: 0.407 sec  <<< FAILURE!
  org.broadleafcommerce.core.pricing.service.exception.PricingException: Unable to execute pricing for order -- id: 24
```

at          org.broadleafcommerce.core.pricing.service.PricingServiceImpl.executePricing(    PricingServiceImpl.java:44)
     at        org.broadleafcommerce.core.order.service.OrderServiceImpl.save(OrderServiceIm   pl.java:276)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl. java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUt      ils.java:317)
      at    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProx      y.java:201)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.save(Unknown Source)
      at  org.broadleafcommerce.core.checkout.service.CheckoutTest.testCheckout(Checkou      tTest.java:115)
      Caused by: org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.WorkflowException:    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No currency conversion service is     registered, cannot add different currency types together (USD INR)
      at    org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.DefaultErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultEr      rorHandler.java:60)
      at     org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor.doActivities(SequencePr      ocessor.java:90)
      at      org.broadleafcommerce.core.pricing.service.PricingServiceImpl.executePricing(      PricingServiceImpl.java:39)
      ... 47 more
      Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No currency       conversion service is registered, cannot add different currency types        together (USD INR)
      at org.broadleafcommerce.common.money.Money.add(Money.java:182)
      at       org.broadleafcommerce.core.pricing.service.workflow.TotalActivity.setTaxSums(      TotalActivity.java:135)
      at org.br             oadleafcommerce.core.pricing.service.workflow.TotalActivity.execute(TotalActi      vity.java:48)
      at       org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor.doActivities(SequencePr      ocessor.java:77)
      ... 48 more

I hence cannot run the projects .Can any one please help . 
I would also like to know why there is no demosite sub-module in the framework code . How to run the frame work source code from eclipse . I also don't see any build.xml files like we had in demosite project .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to build Broadleaf Commerce's framework project from source . If your aim is to change the Broadleaf Logo you don't need to build the entire Broadleaf framework  source code .

All you need is to override certain portions of the DemoSite source code . Suggest you search this forum for more details regarding this issue .

Hope this helps . Good luck .